# FabricJS Text vs NodeJs Node Canvas Text - The Fonts Look Different

Tags: node.js, fabricjs

I am really stressed out with this, i have built an entire designer with Fabricjs, gone through some right hoops with the text to make it work how it's needed. The problem is now when the data from the canvas is sent to the server for a full resolution render with NodeJs (fabricjs in node) the fonts are coming out looking different to they do in the browser.

All the fonts are installed on the server, and the correct font does render, it just seems to have different spacing between the characters even though the fabric version is the same and all the extension code is the same on browser and server side, all the TTF fonts are the same etc etc

Here is the browser version:

[image]

And here is the node js version:

[image]

As you can see the font is correct on the node one compared to the browser one, but it's being rendered slightly differently.

Is there a solution anyone knows of to fix this?

Comment: Are you using ```node-canvas``` on the server as in the official Fabric.js tutorials? It uses Cairo, which is not necessarily the same renderer that a browser will use so the differences may come from that. I also suspect that the difference is because the browser image has the text body scaled down after rasterization, which would lead to differences in font weight and spacing compared to rasterizing at the intended size.

Comment: @Romen Yes, it's just the Josefin Sans font, everything else is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any way to solve this problem when using fabric.js

Text in fabric.js can be scaled arbitrarily, but then it is rasterized and displayed as a canvas object like any other image.

You can see in the fabric.js demos that the text will stretch like an image until your input is complete, then it re-renders to a new image at that scale.

[image: Before, during, and after scaling a textbox in fabric.js]

Knowing that this is how fabric.js handles text, it is possible to select two scales that produce quite different results:

[image: Two text bodies of similar size with very different weights.]

In the image above you can see that the two fonts are pretty much the same size, but the one on the right (slightly larger) has been rasterized such that it appears to have a bolder appearance. It's the best example I could reproduce with limited time.

This is why rendering the fabric.js objects in your browser at a smaller resolution than the server will lead to the font appearing slightly different.

If you try rendering the browser version at the same size as the server you are likely going to get the same results.

Comment: Well we’ve actually extended fabric to have rich text editing features so we never scale text in the default fashion it’s done with font size on a fixed container. It’s literally the Josefin sans font. We’ve actually worked out that it’s the font not the canvas or fabric in this case, josefin is a strange font and if you try applying bold or italic  to Regular it acts weird, so you have to use the extra bold and italic versions instead

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood your last comment which led to writing this answer.  I guess this answer might still help somebody else who ends up here with the stock fabric.js